# How to update HtmlDisplayName on a NetBeans AbstractNode

Tags: netbeans, rcp

I am working on NetBeans Platform 6.7

I have a simple BeanTreeView to display some nodes. They all start in normal text and I wish to change some of them to **bold** and/or underline, in response to events in the software.

Trouble is, I cannot see how to get the Tree to refresh the Nodes display.

I can call AbstractNode.setName() which will allow me to change the name but will not support the bold tags.

I can change the result of getHtmlDisplayName() to include bold tags.
But then I must get the Node to be repainted - how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.
It looks like I am being thick.

I can call **Node.setDisplayName()** on the Node, and the **Node.getHtmlDisplayName()** will be automatically called as a result - as long as the I have actually changed the **DisplayName** string - If I call **setDisplayName()** with the same string as before, then nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from within your AbstractNode (in a `PropertyChangeListener` or similar which picks up the change)

```
fireDisplayNameChange("", getDisplayName());
```

This will bypass the check to see if the display name has changed!
Just make sure you have code to change the HTML in your `getHtmlDisplayName()` method

Answer (score 0):

I can work around my problem if I stop caching **AbstractNode**s; when I want to update the **HtmlDisplayName()** of an **AbstractNode** instance I must construct a replacement Node.

It does not seem to be possible to simply update the existing node and get it refreshed.